# Unable to load Tao.DevIl.dll

Tags: dll, load, devil

### Windows 7 64 Bit

i have downloaded Tao framework to work with Opengl and DevIl together. the problem is when i try to use devIl library i get this error under 64 bit platform ( settings > build > platform  target)

```
Unable to load DLL 'DevIL.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

when trying to use the library under 32bit platform, i get thise error

```
Unable to load DLL 'DevIL.dll': The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent TaoFramework doesn't have DevIL binding in its sources.

I searched, and I found an older version of Tao, previsely [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Tao). From there, you can compiler Tao.DevIL library, which requires DevIL 1.6.8 RC2, which you can find it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openil/files/DevIL%20Win32/1.6.8%20RC%202/); download the binary, or compile your self the project from the sources.

Make to sure have the DLL in you path.

If you want to run on Windows, I suppose you shall modify the sources in order to point correctly to the DLL file; if running on 64 bit platform, I suppose you shall point to the 64 bit version of DevIL.

(You're lucky, I've investigated just right now).